# Plotting 3D truncated cone in matlab

Tags: matlab

How can I plot a 3D nodes in a shape of truncated cone using matlab, and I want to connect each two nodes together with line.

Comment: Are you trying to draw a wire frame of a truncated cone?  The wording of your question is a little confusing

Answer (score 0):

Here is a truncated cone (based on http://msemac.redwoods.edu/~darnold/math50c/matlab/coordcyl/index.xhtml). I'm not sure if this is the type of mesh you are looking for.

```
r=linspace(1,2,25);
theta = linspace(0,2*pi,25);
[r,theta] = meshgrid(r,theta);
x = r.*cos(theta);
y = r.*sin(theta);
z = -r;
mesh(x,y,z)
```

Comment: Thank u very much for ur replay, what I am trying to do is to generate a random nodes (x,y,z) inside this truncated cone.and then connect each 2 nodes together by a line. those lines suppose to be about the same size.

Comment: do you have a method to generate the pairs of points and need a way to plot them? Do you also need a way to generate the points?